# Using LibreOffice-Draw to open a Visio .vsd files

Tags: microsoft-visio-2007

When I use LibreOffice-Draw to open a mechanical drawing created in Visio (.vsd) 2007, all dimension guide lines appear as arrow heads. All other aspects of the drawing are correct. Any explanation? Any setting in LibreOffice-Draw to correct this? Is the problem in the old 2007 version of Visio?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.